# Where to find downloaded plugins of sbt?

Tags: scala, plugins, sbt, ivy

I know that downloaded dependencies of `sbt` are stored in `~/.ivy2/cache` on unix and `c:\Users\<username>\.ivy2\cache` on windows, but where do plugins go? I'm pretty sure they are not stored locally in the project, because I've added one plugin (`sbt-assembly` in my case) to one project, and after restarting sbt it started downloading the plugin from `https://repo.scala-sbt.org`, but next time I added it to another project, it was available without downloading, so it must be somewhere on my local filesystem, but where exactly?

Comment: What version of sbt are you using? Since sbt 1.3.0, sbt retrieves dependencies using coursier instead of ivy, so the cache location is different and is OS-specific. On MacOS, it's `~/Library/Caches/Coursier`. It doesn't matter whether we're talking about project-level dependencies or build-level dependencies such as plugins.

Answer (score 3):

It's in the exact same location. sbt plugins are just ivy artifacts, so they go into the same cache. Though with current sbt versions it's probably using coursier rather than ivy.